# How do I move between windows in IRSSI?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, irssi

In IRSSI, I've always been able to use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> or  <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to jump directly to specific windows. That seems to have stopped working. I think it probably happened with the update to 15.04, but I can't swear to that.

I can still use  <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>-></kbd> or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to cycle through windows but I don't see a way to hop right to the window I want anymore. So ... how do I get that functionality back? Or is there a new way I can hop straight to a specific window in irssi?

Comment: This question should be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/, it's definitely not Ubuntu Linux specific (not even Linux specific).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally worked this out. The <kbd>alt</kbd>+number conflicts with gnome-terminal's keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs. That was always the case, but in older versions of gnome-terminal the combo would switch tabs if there were tabs to switch to and switch IRSSI windows if there weren't.

If you disable or re-map the "Switch to Tab ..." shortcuts (at Terminal > Preferences >  Shortcuts) you can use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> in IRSSI again.

Double-click on the shortcut key and you'll see "New accelerator..." -- from there <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will disable the shortcut, or you can create a new shortcut. I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: Escape also works as Alt key. So you can use Esc+2 to move to window numbered 2.

Comment: this also happens to me in freebsd in vbox.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the commands `/1`, `/2`, ... `/N`, which is what I like to do.

Comment: This does not work

Comment: This works, but its not a keystroke. Its a command you enter into irssi, like /join #servername. eg type "/1" and hit enter, and it will switch to window 1. "/8" and enter will switch to window 8.

Comment: I prefer this instead of overwriting other programs settings.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Terminal` icon > `Preferences` > `Shortcuts`

Then, uncheck `Enable Shortcuts`

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for example will work now. The problem for the terminal window is that the alt keys are mapped to switching to the terminal tabs (if you use those).